# Read local JSON file with javascript to write into HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, json

Is there a way I can read a local JSON file created by the server side into an object in js. So that I can append that data into HTML tags and further create a table of the all that content.

I tried searching a lot and all I found was ajax and jquery which I haven't learnt yet.

Comment: where is this file that you are trying to access?

Comment: In a subfolder. saved locally by the filesystem module (node.js)

Comment: you can use the same module to read the file and parse it, however am not sure how your html is rendered? are you using pug and or others to render the html?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments - since you mentioned you already have a [file system module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-system) on a node.js app that saves the said file, am simply making some assumptions here and giving you an idea on how to read the file. Assuming your file is a `json` file, using the file system  module

```
var fs = require('fs')
var file = '{yourfolder}/sample.json'
var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file, 'UTF-8'))
```

Comment: He isn't using `node` most probably.

Comment: I am using node but it's in a complete different js file. I tried the fs module in a script tag just below the HTML body tag and it says "cant find variable require "

Comment: not sure what you mean by "complete different" js file? post your structure and more information along with your question - else no one can help

Comment: alternatively is there a way I can pass some contents/data from the server.js file to my HTML file? Couz i created the json file just for the purpose to get the data to my html file.

Comment: @AryanArora you need to use some view/template engine for that like pug, ejs, handlebars, etc.

Comment: @AryanArora use your favourite search engine to search about these view engines. They would be helpful for you.